# C++: El programa siempre devuelve la misma cantidad de números pares

Tags: c++

Enunciado: Hacer un programa que imprima los números pares hasta el 300 y que imprima cuántos números pares hay.

Mi problema es que a la hora de imprimir la cantidad de números pares me muestra 4, siendo que hay más.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int par = 0;
    do
    {
        if (par % 2 == 0)
            cout << par << " ";
        par++;
    }
    while (par <= 300);

    int sum = 0;
    while (par > 0) {
        sum += par % 10;
        par /= 10;
    }

    cout << "\n La cantidad de numeros pares encotrados es: " << sum << endl;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mi problema es que a la hora de imprimir la cantidad de numeros pares me muestra 4 y siendo que hay mas

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 5):

Así no cuentas los pares que hay entre cero y tres cientos:

```
do
{
    if (par % 2 == 0)
    cout << par << " ";
    par++;
}
while(par <= 300);
```

Así cuentas todos los números del cero al tres cientos (un total de 301 números) y sólo imprimes los pares. Seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
int par = 0;
for (int numero = 0; numero <= 300; ++numero)
{
    if (numero % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << par << " ";
        par++;
    }
}
```

Pero no necesitas un bucle para saber la cantidad de números pares entre dos cifras, te basta con saber cuántos números hay y sabes que la mitad de ellos serán pares:

```
int pares_entre(int inicio, int fin)
{
    return ((fin - inicio) + 1) / 2;
}
```

Comment: `pares_entre(1,3) == pares_entre(2,4) == 1`. Si se dijese que `fin` no entra en el intervalo entonces tendríamos que `pares_entre(1,4) == pares_entre(2,5) == 1` que seguiría siendo incorrecto

Comment: Si la ventana tiene un tamaño impar, el número de pares puede oscilar dependiendo de si el primer número de la ventana es par o impar: `IMPAR PAR IMPAR -> 1 par` `PAR IMPAR PAR -> 2 pares`

Comment: En tu primera parte de la respuesta dices que así no se cuentan los pares; pero esa porción de código es la que simplemente imprime los pares que evidentemente no cuenta pares y tampoco es donde falla el usuario. Y en la última parte muestras un código donde realmente tampoco se cuentan así los pares. Lo único que veo es que aportas optimizar el bucle while por for, lo demás está mal.

Comment: @AntonioS.F. Según tu análisis ¿Dónde falla el usuario? Si hay una parte de mostrar pares ¿Cuál es la parte de contarlos? No optimizo el bucle `while` cambiándolo por un `for`, es igual de ineficiente un bucle que el otro, pero uno cuenta pares y el otro no.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, buenas en el segundo bucle while de la pregunta es donde el usuario intenta contar los pares.

Comment: @AntonioS.F. El objetivo del segundo `while` difícilmente será contar los pares cuando lo que hace es actualizar una variable `sum` y dividir el recuento anterior entre diez.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, precisamente ahí es donde surge el problema ya que mostrar mostraba bien los números el código, lo que hacía mal lo hacía el usuario en ese bucle como indico en mi respuesta y lo  que pretendía era contar cuántos pares había mostrado.

Comment: @AntonioS.F. estoy en completo desacuerdo con tu análisis. El segundo bucle nunca fue diseñado para contar pares, la operación que pretende hacer ahí es otra.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster pues mi deducción está basada en la lógica. El código muestra al final el texto "La cantidad de numeros pares encotrados es: " y el valor de  **sum**, y en la única porción del código que opera con dicha variable es el segundo bucle que el usuario se armó un lío. Para no extender lo que podamos opinar voy a modificar mi respuesta con for y con pares_entre para que le eches un vistazo.

Comment: @AntonioS.F. sigo en completo desacuerdo con tu análisis. El texto de los pares encontrados es independiente de ambos bucles, imprime `sum` (**sum**atorio) no `par` (**par**es), el primer bucle hace distinción entre pares e impares y el segundo sólo suma cosas sin sentido.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, el código es simple, veamos el usuario llama par a la variable que recorre el bucle desde 0 a 300, es para lo que sirve par. Tú estás asociando el nombre de la variable al rol (por eso la importancia de nombrar adecuadamente las variables). El usuario usa la operación módulo para averiguar si su variable par es un número par y lo imprime. Esa parte del código hace su función bién (con variable mal nombrada). Y en el segundo bucle el usuario se hace un lío y veo que tú también tratando de darle lógica a lo que no la tiene. A veces no vemos lo evidente, a mí también me pasa.

Comment: @AntonioS.F. sigo en completo desacuerdo con tu análisis. Donde tú ves una "conclusión basada en la lógica" y "no vemos lo evidente" yo veo un bucle que busca pares (el primero) y un bucle que hace algo de sumar y módulos de diez (el segundo). Ninguna lógica ni evidencia de que el segundo bucle sea la búsqueda de pares, ni siquiera en tu código, que eliminas dicho bucle.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, me sorprendes cada vez más. Lo que propuso el usuario fue imprimir los números pares de 0 a 300 y contar cuántos pares había. La primera parte la logró en el primer bucle; y la metedura de pata en el segundo. Y la lógica de esto es aplastante. Tu respuesta comienza mal porque no es ahí donde trata de contar los pares; usas for que según tú es igual de ineficiente que while y aportas una forma de contar cuántos pares hay en una serie consecutiva que es errónea. Y no entiendo la lógica de los votos positivos en una repuesta con errores.

Comment: @AntonioS.F. Es halagador que te pueda sorprender, gracias. Sigo estando en completo desacuerdo con tu análisis, y con tu visió de lo que es una "*lógica aplastante*". El objetivo es claro: contar pares, lo que infieras alrededor es indiferente. Por favor, dime ¿En qué es errónea la forma en que propongo contar pares con un `for`?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster En tanto no obedece a las dos primeras líneas de la pregunta, que es:   Hacer un programa que imprima los números pares hasta el 300 y que imprima cuántos números pares hay. Tu código reemplaza la primera parte del código del usuario (correcta) que hacía bien eso imprimir los pares y lo que haces tú es imprimir 0, 1, 2, 3 ... nada que ver con la cuestión del enunciado; y además tu fórmula de calcular entre_pares también es errónea. Revisa mi respuesta y verás que se ajusta al enunciado y además es correcta.

Comment: Tu bucle tampoco sigue las dos primeras líneas de la pregunta, al fin y al cabo la impresión de cuántos pares hay se hace **fuera** del bucle. ¿Dices que todo el bucle es incorrecto porque dicho bucle NO hace una cosa que NO debe hacer? Tu respuesta no es ni más ni menos correcta, es simplemente más parecida al (incorrecto e ineficiente) código original.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, tu función pares_entre(2,6) retorna 2 en lugar de 3. Esa función es incorrecta y así no se calculan los pares que hay en un rango de números consecutivos. La pregunta era imprimir los números pares (tú imprimes 0,1,2,3...) y contar cuántos hay. Y aportas una función para ese cálculo que es incorrecta. Revisa y modifica tu respuesta porque hay gente votando positivamente una respuesta con errores.

Comment: @AntonioS.F. si alguien considera que la respuesta es incorrecta es libre de votar negativamente. Es cierto que `pares_entre` no devuelve los pares entre [X, Y] si no entre [X, Y), como también  es cierto que la pregunta no va de imprimir pares si no (como el título indica) contar pares.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster buenas, pues es cierto cada cual evidentemente es libre de votar lo que quiera aunque sea incorrecto.

Answer (score 4):

El problema de tu código es que así no se cuentan los números pares:

```
int sum = 0;
while (par > 0) {
   sum += par % 10;
   par /= 10;
}
```

Has de utilizar el primer bucle para ello, y olvidarte de eso de arriba que no sé qué es lo que hace siquiera. En tu bucle de impresión puedes aprovechar que preguntas si un número es par para imprimirlo y hacer que ahí haya un contador. Quedaría así:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   int par = 0;
   int sum = 0;
   do
   {
       if (par % 2 == 0) // Si el número es par
       {
           cout << par << " ";  // Lo imprime
           sum++;               // lo cuenta
       }
       par++;

   } while(par < 301);
 
    cout << "\n La cantidad de numeros pares encotrados es: " << sum << endl;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Segunda Versión**

Aquí va una versión en la que usamos un bulce for en lugar de while lo que hace ya innecesario la variable *par* que queda cubierta por la propia variable del bucle.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

   int numPares = 0;
   for(int num=0; num < 301; num++)
   {
       if (num % 2 == 0) // Si el número es par
       {
           cout << num << " ";  // Lo imprime
           numPares++;          // lo cuenta
       }
   }
 
   cout << "\n La cantidad de numeros pares encotrados es: " << numPares << endl;
   system ("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Si quisiéramos saber la cantidad de números pares que hay en un intervalo consecutivo de números podemos hacer uso del siguiente método:

```
int pares_entre(int inicio, int fin)
{
    int nItems = (fin - inicio + 1);
    // Si el número de elementos es par sabemos que los pares son
    // justo la mitad. Así que investigamos para cuando dicha cantidad
    // de elementos es impar: 
    if (nItems % 2 != 0)
        // El caso que experimenta variación es si el número inicial 
        // es par, implica que al ser el número de elementos impares el
        // ultimo también es par y por eso añadimos al resultado + 1;
        if (inicio % 2 == 0)
           return (nItems / 2) + 1;


    return (nItems / 2);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Si la variable para contar los pares se llama `sum`, ¿cómo se llamaría la variable si ahora te piden sumarlos?.

Comment: Simplemente una suma total. Cuando imprimes el número, ya sabes su valor que está en la variable par. Te creas un contafor SumTotal = SumTotal + par; y lo metes dentro del condicional justo después de imprimirlo.

Comment: Aunque si lo que dices es cómo llamar a las variables yo la llamaría en lugar de par pondría num, a la que llamas sum, la llamaría numPares, y al sumatorio de esos números numSumPares. Así sería más legible y entendible el código aunque es simple.

Comment: Nunca llamaría `sum` a una variable. Va contra las buenas prácticas y la legibilidad. En su lugar, yo la llamaría `numerosPares`, o incluso `numeroParesHasta300`. El código se explica solo, es legible, y en caso de modificación no tienes que estar pensando en que `sum` no era una suma, sino la cuenta de números pares hasta 300.

Comment: Un detalle... para bucles en los que los límites están acotados es preferible usar `for` frente a `while` o `do-while`. Nota además que `for` te permite reducir el ámbito del contador `par`, lo cual también suele ser beneficioso

Answer (score 3):

Aparte de las 2 respuestas que ya te han dado, hagamos un ejercicio mental. Te piden mostrar por pantalla todos los números pares hasta el 300 y que te imprima cuántos números pares hay.

Necesitaremos un bucle para esta tarea (¿existirá otra manera de mostrar los números pares sin realizar un ciclo iterativo?).

Tu primer bucle dice así:

```
for(int i = 0; i <=300; i++) {
  //...
}
```

Esto se traduce al castellano como:

> Desde `i` igual a cero, hasta `i` menor o igual a 300, iterar sumando 1 unidad en cada iteración.

Tenemos entonces 301 iteraciones (desde 0 hasta 300 hay 301 valores).

Sin embargo podemos simplificar la cantidad de iteraciones si aumentamos en 2 unidades el iterador en vez de 1 sola unidad.

```
for(int = 0; i < 301; i += 2) {
  //...
}
```

Ahora tenemos muchas menos iteraciones (151 en este caso) y lo único que debemos hacer es mostrar el iterador, que esta vez avanzará de 2 en 2 cayendo precisamente en números pares: 0, 2, 4, ..., 300

Luego, aprovechando que estamos iterando podemos contar el número de iteraciones para saber cuántos pares hemos mostrado por pantalla, para ello simplemente antes de iniciar el bucle establecemos una variable de tipo entero inicializada en cero. Luego en cada iteración aumentamos en 1 unidad dicha variable.

Por ejemplo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int cantidadPares = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 301; i += 2) {
      cout << i << " ";
      cantidadPares++;
    }

    cout << "\n La cantidad de numeros pares encontrados es: " << cantidadPares << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

El resultado de la última sentencia `cout` será:

> La cantidad de numeros pares encontrados es: 151

Muchos pensarían que sólo habría 150, ya que la mitad de 300 es precisamente 150, pero estamos iterando desde cero (0) por lo tanto hay 1 número par adicional. Se puede consultar [paridad del cero](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paridad_del_cero#:%7E:text=El%200%20es%20par.,%2C%200%20%3D%200%20%C3%97%202.).

Espero que mi aporte te de otra idea para solucionar el problema.